# Why couldn't Draco Malfoy testify that Voldemort was back?

Tags: harry-potter

Draco Malfoy is the son of a death eater, and he obviously knew that Voldemort was back. There is at least one moment where he acknowledged the Dark Lord's return: in the train compartment at the end of the fourth book (last chapter).

The Ministry was flatly denying the Dark Lord's return, so why couldn't Dumbledore feed some veritaserum to Draco (or any other death eater's son, for that matter)?

Answer (score 8):

Draco *could* testify that Voldemort had returned, but:

1. Nobody asked him to testify;
2. At the time of the boasting in the fourth book, he was not an eyewitness to Voldemort's return, so he would be reporting hearsay;
3. If Voldemort wanted it kept quiet, Draco would have obeyed.

As for Dumbledore feeding him Veritaserum, why would he need Draco's testimony in the first place? The people who would have listened to any such demonstration already believed Harry when he made the exact same claim. Everyone else was already determined to stick with the official line from the Ministry, no matter what.

Answer (score 8):

You ask why Dumbledore didn't give someone veritaserum, and then try to use this evidence to persuade the ministry to accept this as truth.

This happened in Goblet of Fire:

> Snape handed Dumbledore a small glass bottle of completely clear liquid: the Veritaserum with which he had threatened Harry in class. [...] Dumbledore forced the man’s mouth open and poured three drops inside it. Then he pointed his wand at the man’s chest and said,
>
> “Rennervate.”
>
> Crouch’s son opened his eyes. His face was slack, his gaze unfocused. Dumbledore knelt before him, so that their faces were level.
>
> “Can you hear me?” Dumbledore asked quietly.
>
> The man’s eyelids flickered.
>
> “Yes,” he muttered.
>
> “I would like you to tell us,” said Dumbledore softly, “how you came to be here. How did you escape from Azkaban?”
>
> *Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35* (Veritaserum)

Dumbledore, freshly armed with Crouch's testimony obtained with veritaserum, tried to tell Fudge that Voldemort had returned. He also had McGonnagall, Snape, and Harry to vouch for him.

> “You-Know-Who... returned? Preposterous. Come now, Dumbledore...”
>
> “As Minerva and Severus have doubtless told you,” said Dumbledore, “we heard Barry Crouch confess. **Under the influence of Veritaserum**, he told us how he was smuggled out of Azkaban, and how Voldemort — learning of his continued existence from Bertha Jorkins — went to free him from his father and used him to capture Harry. The plan worked, I tell you. Crouch has helped Voldemort to return.”
>
> “See here, Dumbledore,” said Fudge, and Harry was astonished to see a slight smile dawning on his face, “you — you can’t seriously believe that. You-Know-Who — back? Come now, come now... certainly, Crouch may have believed himself to be acting upon You-Know-Who’s orders — but to take the word of a lunatic like that, Dumbledore...”
>
> *Goblet of Fire, Chapter 36* (The Parting Of The Ways)

And you can see how well that turned out. Quite simply, if the ministry of magic would not believe 3 adult witnesses to a death eater's testimony, they would not believe any number of witnesses to a child's testimony.

And once they refuted Dumbledore's claims, Lucius would make matters very hard for Dumbledore for forcing veritaserum on his son.

Answer (score -1):

Dumbledore wouldnt want to hurt his student  , even if he is the son of a death eater or the boy who lived makes no difference to him. To him all are equal.  It is immoral to use veritaserum on someone without their permission unless they are a criminal.

Even if Dumbledore fed veritaserum to Draco, Fudge won't still believe it. After all,  who is going to believe an underage wizard  ( as evinced at the end of the third book ) ? 
Fudge might assume that Dumbledore had confounded Draco and what not. ..

Lastly, let's not talk about what Lucius Malfoy would do if he learned that his son had been used. ...